# How to change backcolor of GridControl (DevEkspress)

Tags: grid

Hi How can i change backcolor of gridcontrol(gridview devekspres)

example;

dim r=10
datagridview1.rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.backcolor=color.red

(datagridview codes not working with gridcontrol(gridview devekspres)

What I have tried:

i used
GridView2.Appearance.FocusedRow.BackColor = Color.Red

but its colored only focused row